# What can we learn from Barak's stipulation that Deborah accompany him as he mustered the Israelite men for war, & from Deborah's response?

Tags: historical-interpretation, judges, layers-of-meaning, intertextuality

What can we learn from Barak's stipulation that Deborah accompany him as he mustered the Israelite men for war, & from Deborah's response?

I might just be asking the obvious.  Is Barak's stipulation request an example of a person who is fearful(or even apathetic)  about taking an initiative regarding a prophecy over them?  Is it an example of a person missing a opportunity in life to do something great?
If Barak is showing apathy then is Barak's action similar to Joash the king of Israel's response in 2 Kings 13:14-19 where Joash seems to have shot the arrows with his bow in an apathetic manner?

> Judges 4:6-10
>
> New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 6 Now she sent and summoned Barak the son of Abinoam from
> Kedesh-naphtali, and said to him, “[a]Behold, the Lord, the God of
> Israel, has commanded, ‘Go and march to Mount Tabor, and take with you
> ten thousand men from the sons of Naphtali and from the sons of
> Zebulun. 7 I will draw out to you Sisera, the commander of Jabin’s
> army, with his chariots and his [b]many troops to the river Kishon,
> and I will give him into your hand.’” 8 Then Barak said to her, “If
> you will go with me, then I will go; but if you will not go with me, I
> will not go.” 9 She said, “I will surely go with you; nevertheless,
> the honor shall not be yours on the journey that you are about to
> take, for the Lord will sell Sisera into the hands of a woman.” Then
> Deborah arose and went with Barak to Kedesh. 10 Barak called Zebulun
> and Naphtali together to Kedesh, and ten thousand men went up [c]with
> him; Deborah also went up with him.

> 2 Kings 13:14-19
>
> New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> Death of Elisha
>
> 14 When Elisha [a]became sick with the illness of which he was to die,
> Joash the king of Israel came down to him and wept over [b]him and
> said, “My father, my father, the chariots of Israel and its horsemen!”
> 15 Elisha said to him, “Take a bow and arrows.” So he [c]took a bow
> and arrows. 16 Then he said to the king of Israel, “Put your hand on
> the bow.” And he put his hand on it, then Elisha laid his hands on the
> king’s hands. 17 He said, “Open the window toward the east,” and he
> opened it. Then Elisha said, “Shoot!” And he shot. And he said, “The
> Lord’s arrow of victory, even the arrow of victory over Aram; for you
> will [d]defeat the Arameans at Aphek until you have [e]destroyed
> them.” 18 Then he said, “Take the arrows,” and he took them. And he
> said to the king of Israel, “Strike the ground,” and he struck it
> three times and [f]stopped. 19 So the man of God was angry with him
> and said, “You should have struck five or six times, then you would
> have struck Aram until you would have [g]destroyed it. But now you
> shall strike Aram only three times.”

What can we learn from Barak's stipulation that Deborah accompany him as he mustered the Israelite men for war, & from Deborah's response?

I might just be asking the obvious.  Is Barak's stipulation request an example of a person who is fearful(or even apathetic)  about taking an initiative regarding a prophecy over them?   Is it an example of a person missing a opportunity in life to do something great?
If Barak is showing apathy then is Barak's action similar to Joash the king of Israel's response in 2 Kings 13:14-19 where Joash seems to have shot the arrows with his bow in an apathetic manner?

Comment: Deborah's song is, in fact, a duet 'I,I'. Although she judged Israel, as a prophetess, nevertheless she did so in conjunction with Barak. (Much as Priscilla always acted with her husband Aquila.) Barak may have desired Deborah's presence as a Judge, in that he does not wish to take initiative without her presence, but he does not expect her to act alone, either. This is an interpretation (though I believe it is an intelligent one) so this is a comment not an answer. But up-voted +1, nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

**What are Barak's Feelings Towards the Prophecy?**

We don't know his feelings - we're not told. We are told of his actions - he is prepared to disobey if Deborah does not come with him. He gives an ultimatum. Whatever, his reason for giving such a thing - we can learn that this shouldn't be done. Goes is still patient and merciful and delivers the victory to Barak, but not in the way that it could have been.

**Is Barak Missing Out by Asking Deborah to Accompany Him?**

Yes. Had Barak had greater faith than Sisera would have been given into his hands (verse seven). Instead, he is given into the hands of a woman (verse 9). Jael's hands (verse 21).

**Comparison to Joash**

They are both men who receive a prophecy and fail to act properly rightly to that prophecy and thus are not as blessed as they could be. That's the limit of the link I think. There reactions are different - Joash neglects full investment with the sign act while Barak wants the prophet present at the deed - and the failings of the blessing are different; Barak is reduced in glory, while Joash misses out on a full victory.

Certainly, the two texts can be contrasted but I do not think that they reference one another.